# How to bypass this "script-source 'self' " Chrome Extension Error

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So I'm working on a chrome extension that shortens the URL via goo.gl

This is my actual code, if it may help:

```
 $("#ajaxfiller").text("");
 //Get URL entered
 var longUrl = $("#input2").val();
 longUrl = '"' + longUrl + '"';


 function googlurl(url, cb) {
     jsonlib.fetch({
         url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url',
         header: 'Content-Type: application/json',

         // Just a static URL for shortening:

         data: JSON.stringify({
             longUrl: "https://google.com"
         })
     }, function (m) {
         var result = null;
         try {
             result = JSON.parse(m.content).id;
             if (typeof result != 'string') result = null;
         } catch (e) {
             result = null;
         }
         cb(result);
     });


 }

 googlurl(longUrl, function (s) {
     alert(s);
     $("#kinchyj").show();
     $("#ajaxfiller").val(s);
 });
```

[image: Error]

Note: it acually works, when I load the the extension's `popup.html` as a regular webpage.

It seems this error is a Chrome Security measure. Is there anyway I can white list this in the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the security policy in `manifest.json` using the `content_security_policy` as detailed [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).  What you'd need is:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url; object-src 'self'"
```

I can't tell without seeing the HTML, but you'd be better off moving all of your JavaScript to a *local*, external file included via the `<script>` tag.